# Sql query to get result from 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have following tables structure.Need to select record from all tables those are recently added by added_date.

I am trying to fetch `titlename, sourcename, description, addde_date` from `table1, table2, table3` those are recently added by `added_date`.

Title name and source name are store in Title and source table.

I have try union on these table but `Table3` content the different columns.

**table1**

```
    id   titleid   sourceid     text_content        added_date   -------
    1      15         20         XYzgff       10-10-2012:5:30pm
    2      10         5         gghghggg      10-11-2012:5:30pm
```

**table2**

```
    id   titleid   sourceid    description     added_date   -------
    1       6         8         fhjjjjjkk     11-04-2012:5:30pm 
    2      10         5         gghghggg      10-11-2012:5:30pm
```

**table3**

```
    id       url         Title     Description       added_date       -------------
    1       ggggg        fhhh        llllll         31-04-2012:5:30pm
    2       kkkkkk       ttttt       kkkkkk         10-11-2012:5:30pm
```

**Title** table:

```
    titleid      title_name
      5            lgsfsgsf
      6            lkklgyy
      10           tyyiugj
      15          lklklklkl
```

**Source** table:

```
    sourceid      source_name
       5            jlkjljlj
       8            ghhhhhhh
       20           hhhhhhhf
       6            llllllll
```

Comment: Which SQL flavour is this MSSQL, Oracle, Mysql ... (also which version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UNION`.  Try this (untested):

```
SELECT t.title_name, s.source_name, t1.text_content, t1.added_date   
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Title T 
   ON t1.TitleId = T.TitleId
JOIN Source S 
   ON t1.SourceId = S.SourceId
UNION
SELECT t.title_name, s.source_name, t2.description, t2.added_date   
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Title T 
   ON t2.TitleId = T.TitleId
JOIN Source S 
   ON t2.SourceId = S.SourceId
UNION
SELECT t.title_name, s.source_name, t3.description, t3.added_date   
FROM Table3 t3
JOIN Title T 
   ON t3.TitleId = T.TitleId
JOIN Source S 
   ON t3.SourceId = S.SourceId
```

Well I just realized you don't have a SourceId or TitleId in your Table3.  Not going to be able to get that information, but you could still do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title_Name, Source_Name, Text_Content, Added_Date
FROM 
(
   SELECT t.title_name, s.source_name, t1.text_content, t1.added_date   
   FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN Title T 
     ON t1.TitleId = T.TitleId
   JOIN Source S 
     ON t1.SourceId = S.SourceId
   UNION
   SELECT t.title_name, s.source_name, t2.description, t2.added_date   
   FROM Table2 t2
   JOIN Title T 
     ON t2.TitleId = T.TitleId
   JOIN Source S 
     ON t2.SourceId = S.SourceId
   UNION
   SELECT t3.title, 'Unknown', t3.description, t3.added_date   
   FROM Table3 t3
) t
ORDER BY added_date
```

Comment: :how can i apply order by added_date to the result.and i have title name in  multiple time so can i apply distinct to result .

Comment: UNION should only grab the DISTINCT values -- UNION ALL would return non-distinct values.  With that said, I've edited my reply above to use a subquery with DISTINCT (assuming your RDBMS supports those) and added the ORDER BY clause as well.  Good luck.